# g++ not finding .lib files (vs code)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

ive installed msys2 including g++ and im running into this error:

```
    C:\Users\MYUSER\development\vulkan\MSYS2\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always "--include-directory=C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\include" "-LC:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\lib\x86_64\opencl.lib" -g "C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\Untitled-1.cpp" -o "C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\Untitled-1.exe"
C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\Untitled-1.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\Untitled-1.cpp:68:61: warning: '_cl_command_queue* clCreateCommandQueue(cl_context, cl_device_id, cl_command_queue_properties, cl_int*)' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   68 |         cl_command_queue commandQueue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, deviceID, 0, &ret);
      |                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\Untitled-1.cpp:4:
C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\include/CL/cl.h:1359:1: note: declared here
 1359 | clCreateCommandQueue(cl_context                     /* context */,
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

after adding the include directory:
--include-directory=C:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\include
compilation went further (as shown above) but now im guessing that g++ is not finding the opencl.lib file located here:

```
-LC:\Users\MYUSER\development\code\c++\opencl first steps\lib\x86_64\opencl.lib"
```

whats the magic line? ive tried variations for -L including just the x86_64 directory without the .lib file - no luck.

task.json:

```
 "tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: g++.exe Aktive Datei kompilieren",
        "command": "C:\\Users\\MYUSER\\development\\vulkan\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "--include-directory=${fileDirname}\\include",
            "-L${fileDirname}\\lib\\x86_64\\opencl.lib",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Vom Debugger generierte Aufgabe."
    }
],
"version": "2.0.0"
```

the paths are a bit weird because i started out with one vulkan project and later realized that opencl needs g++ as well.

Comment: Where did you get the .lib file? GCC is supposed to consume .a, not .lib. Since you're using MSYS2, you should just install opencl as a package from it, then ask `pkg-config` for the right compiler flags to use it.

Comment: `"-L${fileDirname}\\lib\\x86_64\\opencl.lib",` the `-L` option of gcc specifies a folder that the linker will search `-l` specifies a library. Also the order of where you put the `-l` can be important.

Comment: OpenCL does not require g++, it works with Visual Studio as well. Seems like you have confused g++ libraries with Visual Studio libraries.

Comment: Try just `${fileDirname}\\lib\\x86_64\\opencl.lib`, `-L` is for library directories, not libraries

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i installed opencl for windows which is apparently not compatible with g++ from msys2. the opencl version from pacman installs a libOpenCL.dll.a file but using this: ` "--include-directory=C:\\Users\\MYUSER\\development\\vulkan\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\include",
     //"-LC:\\Users\\MYUSER\\development\\vulkan\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\lib",
     "-lC:\\Users\\MYUSER\\development\\vulkan\\MSYS2\\mingw64\\lib\\libOpenCL.dll.a"`, does not work (same error as before). tried the -l and the -L version

Comment: Don't try to guess the flags. `pkg-config` will tell you what flags to use.

Comment: never worked with pkg-config before, trying the examples from the manpge does not work. apparently the opencl package name for msys2 is: mingw-w64-x86_64-opencl-icd, running:  pkg-config --cflags --libs mingw-w64-x86_64-opencl-icd
Package mingw-w64-x86_64-opencl-icd was not found